# Insertar registro nuevo en relación many-to-many

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

En la relación mucho a mucho que se establece entre las entidades Diet y WorkDay configuradas de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Diet implements Serializable
{
    // resto de atributos de la entidad

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "diet_workday", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "diet_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "workday_id")})
    private Set<WorkDay> workDays = new HashSet<>();

    // constructor, getter y setter

}

public class WorkDay implements Serializable
{
    // resto de atributos de la entidad

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "workDays", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<Diet> diets = new HashSet<>();

    // constructor, getter y setter

}
```

produce como resultado las siguientes tablas y relación en la base de datos:

[image: relación generada en base de datos]

Inserto en las tablas algunos datos de prueba mediante sentencias SQL:

[image: diet_worday]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El controlador está montado de la siguiente manera:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(Uri.DIET)
public class DietControllerImpl extends Controller<Diet>
{
    @Autowired
    private DietServiceImpl service;

    @RequestMapping(insertOrUpdate)
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> insertOrUpdate(@RequestBody Diet entity)
    {
        return super.returnBoolean(service.insertOrUpdate(entity));
    }
}
```

el servicio:

```
@Service
public class DietServiceImpl extends Services<Diet>
{
    @Autowired
    private DietRepository repository;

    public Boolean insertOrUpdate(Diet entity)
    {
        return repository.save(entity) != null;
    }
}
```

y el repositorio:

```
@Repository
public interface DietRepository extends JpaRepository<Diet, Serializable>
{
    Diet findById(int id);
}
```

El problema con el que me he encontrado es que cuando inserto un json que incluye un diet existente relacionado con un nuevo workday

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Dieta 1",
    "description": "Dieta para recuperar después de entrenar.",
    "kcalTarget": 3600.0,
    "workDays": [
        {
            "dayOfWeek": "WEDNESDAY",
            "name": "Gimnasio",
            "description": "Día de fuerza",
            "kcalTotal": 1950.0,
            "hCarbTotal": 900.0,
            "protTotal": 80.0,
            "fatTotal": 65.0,
            "diets": null
        }
    ]
}
```

elimina las relaciones que había entre ese diet y el resto de workday:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Para poder mantener los registros de las relaciones recupero por un lado el Diet y por otro los Workday que hay en base de datos y los que se reciben de la petición para fusionarlos y terminar añadíendolos al Diet antes de persistir la información. Es funcional pero no me parece una buena solución:

```
@Service
public class DietServiceImpl extends Services<Diet>
{
    @Autowired
    private DietRepository repository;

    public Boolean insertOrUpdate(Diet entity)
    {
        int id = entity.getId();

        // se ejecuta si el que se recibe existe
        if (repository.existsById(id))
        {
            // almacena los workday que recibe por json
            Set<WorkDay> workDayEntity = entity.getWorkDays();

            // recupera el diet por id
            Diet diet = repository.findById(id);

            // almacena los workday del diet
            Set<WorkDay> workDaysDiet = diet.getWorkDays();

            Set<WorkDay> set = new HashSet<>();
            set.addAll(workDayEntity);
            set.addAll(workDaysDiet);

            entity.setWorkDays(null);
            entity.setWorkDays(set);
        }

        return super.insertOrUpdate(repository, entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo estás actualizando el diet con el nuevo workday? ¿Recuperas primero el diet de base de datos y luego añades a la colección de workday uno o estás sobreescribiendo dicha colección?

Comment: He actualizado el post con el código que estoy utilizando para mantener los datos de la base de datos y añadir los nuevos workday recibidos por petición.